# Why does MaterialUI Drawer component link add localhost before the actual external link?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, navigation-drawer, router, drawer

I am trying to add my LinkedIn profile to the drawer component and when I click I get the following in the search bar:

```
http://localhost:3000/https://www.linkedin.com/in/profile-here/
```

My ListItem in the Drawer component:

```
<ListItem
      component={Link}
      to="https://www.linkedin.com/in/profile-here/"
      exact
      button
      key={"LinkedIn"}
>
     <ListItemIcon>
        <LinkedInIcon />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary={"LinkedIn"} />
    </ListItem>
```

I have also tried wrapping the ListItem element in a  tag but I am getting the same results. Example of wrapped ListItem:

```
    <Link to="https://www.linkedin.com/in/profile-here/">
      <ListItem button key={"LinkedIn"}>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <LinkedInIcon />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary={"LinkedIn"} />
      </ListItem>
    </Link>
```

Also I created a simple "About" page and tried adding a link for that as well. Using both the above methods...it seems to work but not behaving as expected.

Instead of navigating to the about page, which just has the following content:

```
<div>This is the about page</div>
```

It shows this in the navbar next to the drawer menu button, when the "About" button in the drawer is clicked:

Before Clicking:         [image]

Clicking to open Drawer: [image]

After Clicking the About link: [image]

Here is the entire Drawer component which I added to my navbar component, in case I messed up somewhere else:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  list: {
    width: 250,
  },
  fullList: {
    width: "auto",
 },
});

function RightDrawer(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    top: false,
    left: false,
    bottom: false,
    right: false,
  });

const toggleDrawer = (anchor, open) => (event) => {
  if (
    event.type === "keydown" &&
    (event.key === "Tab" || event.key === "Shift")
  ) {
    return;
  }

  setState({ ...state, [anchor]: open });
};

const list = (anchor) => (
<div
  className={clsx(classes.list, {
    [classes.fullList]: anchor === "top" || anchor === "bottom",
  })}
  role="presentation"
  onClick={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
  onKeyDown={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
>
  <List>
    <ListItem button key={"About"}>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <InboxIcon />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary={"About"} />
    </ListItem>

    <ListItem button onClick={props.logoutHandler} key={"Logout"}>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <MailIcon />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary={"Logout"} />
    </ListItem>

    <Link to="https://www.linkedin.com/in/faisal-malik-93ab29167/">
      <ListItem button key={"LinkedIn"}>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <LinkedInIcon />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary={"LinkedIn"} />
      </ListItem>
    </Link>
  </List>
  <Divider />
  <List>
    {["All mail", "Trash", "Spam"].map((text, index) => (
      <ListItem button key={text}>
        <ListItemIcon>
          {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary={text} />
      </ListItem>
    ))}
  </List>
  </div>
  );
 var anchor = "right";
 return (
   <div>
  <React.Fragment key={anchor}>
    <Button onClick={toggleDrawer(anchor, true)}>
      <MenuIcon />
    </Button>
    <Drawer
      anchor={anchor}
      open={state[anchor]}
      onClose={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
    >
      {list(anchor)}
    </Drawer>
  </React.Fragment>
  </div>
  );
}

export default RightDrawer;
```

Comment: For external links, you should use the `a` tag instead of `Link` component

Comment: Thanks for that, fixed the first issue!